# Toggling Visibility outside Event Handlers in C#?

Tags: c#, silverlight, visibility

Is there a way to set or reset the visibility dynamically without handling an event?

I am using asynchronous calls and hence the parent loads even before the child does. Due to this, using a routed event handler in the parent always accesses a new object and hence the child element stays collapsed.

I also cannot use a routed event handler in the child because this in turn is executing asynchronously and hence the event is not even triggered!

Comment: A little bit of context/code please. You make plenty of 'the' references just assuming we know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

If you use binding, you can bind the visibility property of your control to a property in your datacontext and use an ivalueconverter to convert from bool to visibility.